# Calling class methods in another python program - Unbound error issue

Tags: python, class, methods

I have a program1.py that has the following structure:

```
    program1.py
        class program1_class()
            def __init(self,var1):
                command1
            def method2(self,var1):
```

Then I have a program2 that imports the the class and needs to access the method2

```
    program2.py
        from  program1_class import program1_class()
        def method2(var1):
           call_method2 = program1_class.method2(var1)
```

When I do this, I get the error

TypeError: unbound method predict_prob() must be called with LogisticRegressionSGD instance as first argument (got list instance instead)

Comment: The number of errors in this code suggests you should start with https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems here-

`from  program1_class import program1_class()` is invalid syntax in several ways.

The correct import statement is
`from program1 import program1_class`

Second, you tried to call a bound instance method on a class.

`call_method2 = program1_class.method2(var1)`

If you look at program1 you'll see that method2 is defined on the instance.  You can tell this because the first argument is `self`.  You call this by intantiating an instance of the class and then calling the method.

`call_method2 = program1_class().method2(var1)`

Comment: He could also define `method2()` as a static method with the `@staticmethod` decorator.